# PHP function work with echo but not with return

Tags: php, function, return, echo

I have this function it allows me to create multi level menu

the problem after I finish the code, using "echo", I tried to make it work in return but it did not give me the sub menu it shows only the main menu!

and If I keep using the echo method i get the code in the top of the page!

any ideas what should I do

Echo code :

```
function showMenu($level = 0,$site_url,$get_type_sec,$get_sub_type_sec) {

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pages WHERE parent_id ='$level' order by navigation_order ASC"); 
echo "<ul>";
    while ($node = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 


            $result2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pages WHERE id ='$node[parent_id]' order by navigation_order ASC"); 
             while ($node2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2)) {$node3="$node2[query_string]/";
             $noder="$node[id]"; 
             $result3 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pages WHERE id ='$node2[parent_id]' order by navigation_order ASC"); 
             while ($node3 = mysql_fetch_array($result3)) {$node2="$node3[query_string]/"; }
             }


            echo "<li><a href='$site_url/$node2$node3$node[query_string]/'> $node[title] </a> ";
            $hasChild = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pages WHERE id ='$node[id]'")) != null;
            // If user request same page open menu 
            IF ($hasChild && $node['query_string']=="$get_type_sec") {
                showMenu($node['id'],$site_url,$get_type_sec,$get_sub_type_sec);    
            }
            elseif($hasChild &&  $node['query_string']=="$get_sub_type_sec") {

                showMenu($node['id'],$site_url,$get_type_sec,$get_sub_type_sec);


            }

            echo "</li>";


    }
echo "</ul>";

}
```

Return Code

```
function showMenu($level = 0,$site_url,$get_type_sec,$get_sub_type_sec) {

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pages WHERE parent_id ='$level' order by navigation_order ASC"); 
$echo = "<ul>";
return = $echo;
    while ($node = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 


            $result2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pages WHERE id ='$node[parent_id]' order by navigation_order ASC"); 
             while ($node2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2)) {$node3="$node2[query_string]/";
             $noder="$node[id]"; 
             $result3 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pages WHERE id ='$node2[parent_id]' order by navigation_order ASC"); 
             while ($node3 = mysql_fetch_array($result3)) {$node2="$node3[query_string]/"; }
             }


            $echo .= "<li><a href='$site_url/$node2$node3$node[query_string]/'> $node[title] </a> ";
return = $echo;
            $hasChild = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pages WHERE id ='$node[id]'")) != null;
            // If user request same page open menu 
            IF ($hasChild && $node['query_string']=="$get_type_sec") {
                showMenu($node['id'],$site_url,$get_type_sec,$get_sub_type_sec);    
            }
            elseif($hasChild &&  $node['query_string']=="$get_sub_type_sec") {

                showMenu($node['id'],$site_url,$get_type_sec,$get_sub_type_sec);
            }

            $echo .= "</li>";
            return = $echo;
    }
$echo .= "</ul>";
return = $echo;
}
```

Comment: `return = $echo;` change it to `return $echo;`. Also where ever you call this function just assign it's return value to a variable and feel happy. thanks

Comment: @mario there is no error at all, the problem is the code it not working as it should be.

Comment: @anantkumarsingh sorry i add `return = $echo` by mistake it is `return $echo` and the code it not displaying as it should be

Comment: As i said when you call this function assign it to a variable. that's it. then that variable have the value and you can use it. if and only if  your returned variable have some value. also echo is reserved keyword so use anyother name for your variable. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Change return = $echo to return $echo;

Answer (score 1):

it turns that I need to add `echo` when I call the function inside it self

```
//before
showMenu($node['id'],$site_url,$get_type_sec,$get_sub_type_sec);
//after
echo showMenu($node['id'],$site_url,$get_type_sec,$get_sub_type_sec);
```

the final code will be:

```
 function showMenu($level = 0,$site_url,$get_type_sec,$get_sub_type_sec) {

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pages WHERE parent_id ='$level' order by navigation_order ASC"); 
$menu= "<ul>";
return $menu;
    while ($node = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 


            $result2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pages WHERE id ='$node[parent_id]' order by navigation_order ASC"); 
             while ($node2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2)) {$node3="$node2[query_string]/";
             $noder="$node[id]"; 
             $result3 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pages WHERE id ='$node2[parent_id]' order by navigation_order ASC"); 
             while ($node3 = mysql_fetch_array($result3)) {$node2="$node3[query_string]/"; }
             }


            $menu.= "<li><a href='$site_url/$node2$node3$node[query_string]/'> $node[title] </a> ";
return $menu;
            $hasChild = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pages WHERE id ='$node[id]'")) != null;
            // If user request same page open menu 
            IF ($hasChild && $node['query_string']=="$get_type_sec") {
                echo showMenu($node['id'],$site_url,$get_type_sec,$get_sub_type_sec);    
            }
            elseif($hasChild &&  $node['query_string']=="$get_sub_type_sec") {

                echo showMenu($node['id'],$site_url,$get_type_sec,$get_sub_type_sec);
            }

            $menu.= "</li>";
            return $menu;
    }
$menu.= "</ul>";
return  $menu;
}
```